# Show that if $\textbf{U}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$, then $A\cap U$ is dense in $\textbf{U}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Defn:** $\textbf{A}$ is a dense subset of  $\mathbb{R^n}$ if $\mathbb{R^n} \subset \overline{A}$

where $\overline{A}= A$ closure

**Defn:** The closure of $A$, is the set $\overline{A}$ consisting of all limit points of $A$.

1)Show that if $\textbf{U}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$, then $A\cap U$ is dense in $\textbf{U}$.

**Attempt:**

1) We are given that $\mathbb{R^n} \subset \overline{A}$  and $\textbf{U}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

This means that $U \subset \mathbb{R^n} \subset \overline{A}$. Therefore $\overline{A}$ contains all of the limit points of $\textbf{U}$. So if we take the intersection of $\overline{A}$ and $U$, we will obtain all of the limit points of $\overline{A\cup U}$ which is what we were trying to show.

Is this the right thought process?

Note: I feel I maybe should've used the sequences of the limit points in some fashion, but I could not deduce any set of steps to lead me to a conclusion.

Comment: Consider $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $U = \mathbb{Q}$. $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $A\cap U = \emptyset$, which is obviously not dense in $U$.

Comment: Note that your definition of "dense" is equivalent to stating that for $A$ dense in $B$, every point of $B$ is either in $A$ or is a limit point of $A$ (i.e. for $x\in B$, every neighborhood $N\subseteq B$ of $x$ has nonempty intersection with $A$; also note that for $B$ open, any set that is open in the subspace topology on $B$ is open in the parent space of $B$). Therefore, for any neighborhood $N$ of $x$ in $U$, $N$ is also a neighborhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and has nonempty intersection with $A$. This should be sufficient background to show that $A\cap U$ is dense in $U$.

Comment: Also note that $\overline{A}\cap U$ being dense in $U$ is very different from $A\cap U$ being dense in $U$, as my counterexample above shows.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: It's a self contained question @Shaun, why make a second post for it and use up resources?

Comment: No: there are two questions. We like to keep questions distinct here. There is no shortage of space for separate questions.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6536/104041) on why you should not ask multiple questions.

Comment: fair enough @Shaun